# Problem with wifi on Dual Boot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless

I've dual booted my legion y530 with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04. The wifi in Ubuntu doesn't work (shows no visible networks) if I've booted it up directly but works when I first boot up windows and then restart to boot ubuntu.
`` sudo lshw -C network` `` shows

```
       *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:3a:4d:45:5a:f9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-39-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.29.244 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:140 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
```

Also when wifi is not working instead of `*-network` it shows `*-generic` and sometimes `*- generic DISABLED`.
I've tried to restart the network driver but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a better driver for this device from Larry Finger's git repo.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot and check that `rtw_8822be` is in use.

Also I suggest to disable "Fast Start" feature in Windows. It can create problems for wireless devices.

Comment: "Fast Start" also causes trouble with shared disks.

Comment: I tried that driver but it seemed to completely break my wifi. I was getting ''No wifi adapter found". Now I have reverted back to the original driver. After some research i Have found this exact same problem reported as a bug [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1875099). My bios is updated to the latest verision according to lenovo Vantage. Also I've already disable secure boot as well as Fast Start